# VS Code PHP Intelephense Extension Wrong Suggestion Path

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, intelephense

I use vscode as my editor and php intelephense as my php formatter. It works well, but when I want to use relative file path For example :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

but my php intelephense always suggest me document root, so i follow that suggestion

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="sites/css/index.css">
```

Here is my folder hierarchy

```
-htdocs/
     -anotherSites/
     -sites/
           -php/
               index.php
           -css/
               style.css
```

so when i follow suggestion from intelephense it produce error wrong path to my css

```
 http://localhost/sites/php/sites/css/style.css
```

obviously the path for style css should be like this

```
http://localhost/sites/css/style.css
```

I know i can manual to add right path but i want to php intelephense suggest me the right path, it will make me easy when i forgot file path. So what is the solution to have right path suggestion ?